# Derived functor not called when passed as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I am using a pattern in my program that calls for the calling of different kinds of functors depending on what the object type is. In the code below, the `b1` object is explicitly instantiated with derived functor type `FunctorX`. But when I make the call in the code, the base functor gets called instead of the derived functor. Why is that?

```
struct Functor
{
  Functor() {}
  ~Functor() {}

  virtual int operator()() { return 33; }
};

struct FunctorX : public Functor
{
  FunctorX() : Functor() {}
  ~FunctorX() {}

  int operator()() { return 44; }
};

template< typename FunctorT >
struct B
{
  B( FunctorT FunctorArg ) : Functor { FunctorArg } {}
  ~B() {}

  FunctorT Functor;
};

int main()
{
  B< Functor > b1 { FunctorX() }; // initialize with derived functor. Derived functor gets instantiated.
  int num = b1.Functor(); // error: calls base functor, not derived functor

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Barry changing B's member functor to a ptr lets me do `B< Functor > b1 { new FunctorX() };` and would fix the slicing. But what would the call be on `b1` then? I keep getting `error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments` when I call `b1.Functor();`.

Comment: @Barry I got it: `int num = (*b1.Functor)();`

Answer (score 0):

`B<Functor>` holds an object of type `Functor`. You can initialize that object with an object of type `FunctorX`, but when stored, the object will be sliced to type `Functor`. Just like `unsigned int i = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()`, where the stored value has type `unsigned int`, even though it's initialized with a value whose type is `unsigned long long`.

Comment: That's not an example of slicing.

Comment: @Barry - it's an example of exactly what it says: "the stored value has type `int`, even though it's initialized with a value whose type is `unsigned long long`". And that's the fundamental issue underlying slicing.

Comment: Narrowing conversions and slicing are different things.

Comment: @Barry -- yes, they are. I haven't said otherwise. Again: the type of the stored value does not depend on the type of the initializer.